# dronekit can not download mission with serial or usb connections

Tags: download, upload, mavlink

i use dronekit for control my quadcopter, i develop and test my code with simulator sucessfull, now switch to real drone, it connect and received mavlink message and my various command in dronekit , but when use download command for download the mission from drone it hange in cmds.wait_ready() and then timeout occured ,while it work properly when used sitl or my hardware work correct in download mission when used missionplanner , i see that some peoples have same problem but don't clear way for solve it

i use 2 diffrent telemetry and usb to serial modul, and write very simple single code that only connect to quadcopter and download mission without any complicated states , but the result was same: timeout on cmds.wait_ready()